# Use Toshiba Function Keys without Toshiba Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, toshiba-laptop, function-keys

How can I use  the Toshiba Function Keys on my [Satellite C655D-S5226](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3048775) without being required to install the huge (40 Mb!) Toshiba Function Key Driver?

Comment: If you think 40 MB is huge, just wait till you run Windows Update.

Comment: @Jason I Know, I Know, but still, do little bits of code for keyboard drivers really need to be so HUGE?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I recently disabled the Toshiba Function Key Main Module (TCrdMain) and Toshiba Hotkey Driver (Thotkey) using the MS *Sysinternals* app, *Autoruns* v. 13.01 and notice **no** difference in behavior in *Window 8.1*. The function keys behave normally without pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> (as desired), and with <kbd>Fn</kbd>, perform the expected secondary funtions, e.g. <kbd>F2</kbd> dims the screen, <kbd>F11</kbd> mutes sound.

Using Autoruns, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902, or Nirsoft's WhatsInStartup, http://nirsoft.net/utils/what_run_in_startup.html, allows you to disable  (or to re-enable) these utilities with a click in a checkbox, so there's little risk or effort in testing.